# Paypal Subscription error india merchant india customer payment error

Tags: paypal

I have implemented the PayPal subscription buttons in my website. After selecting credit/debit card payment mode and selecting India as country, PayPal shows this error message:

> We're sorry, due to government regulations, buyers having a billing address in India cannot use PayPal to make payments to sellers registered in India.

[image: Screenshot wit PayPal window]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Helpfully, the error message in your screenshot completely explains the exact issue. Due to Indian government regulations, Indian customers cannot pay Indian merchants via the PayPal service (because the Indian government is nationalistic/protectionist and does not like people *within* the country using services from other countries)

Only cross-border (international) transactions are permitted, where one of the parties is *not* in India.